# Run loop in javascript for confirm alert?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Here my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var con=confirm("Are You Want to add More Packages");
        if(con==true)
        {
            var radio1=document.getElementById('first_radio');
            if(radio1.checked==true)
            {

                var a=document.getElementById('total').value;
                b=(parseInt(a)+parseInt(a));
                document.getElementById('total').value=b;
                var c=confirm("Are You Want to add More Packages")
                if(c==true)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("you clicked Cancel");
        }  
    }
</script>
```

In this code i want to run that addition upto user click cancel in confirm alert. any one help? Thanks advance..

Comment: Loops are among the most basic constructs, and you should be able to find literally thousands of examples showing the different types of loops available in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var con=confirm("Are You Want to add More Packages");
        if(con==true)
        {
            var radio1=document.getElementById('first_radio');
            if(radio1.checked==true)
            {
                var a=document.getElementById('total').value;
                b=(parseInt(a)+parseInt(a));
                document.getElementById('total').value=b;
                validate();// call this function again from here
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("you clicked Cancel");
        }  
    }
</script>
```